# Laravel why does post request return status 302 instead of 422 when testing missing fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I am trying to test validation on a Laravel page

```
    public function user_can_create_event_page()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create();
        $event = Event::factory()->make()->toArray();
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/events', $event);
        $response->assertStatus(302);
        $this->assertNotNull(Event::where('name', $event['name'])->first());
    }

    public function user_receives_error_422_if_name_is_not_provided()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create();
        $event = Event::factory()->state(['name' => ''])->make()->toArray();
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/events', $event);
        $response->assertStatus(422);
    }
```

and in my validation

```
class EventStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return auth()->check();
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' =>'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::resource('events', EventController::class);
```

**EventController.php**

```
    public function store(EventUpdateRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $event = Event::create($request->all());
        auth()->user()->events()->save($event);
        return redirect()->route('events.show', ['event' => $event->id])
            ->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
    }
```

The first test passes but the second fails. If I try in my app on the browser the app works as expected and I receive back the message 'The name field is required'.

How can I write this test to check that the request fails with validation error?

### Update

Logging `$event` gives below object as expected

```json
{"name":"","event_type_id":20}
```

Currently I am receiving status 302

Interestingly I have also noted that if I change `post` to `postJson` now my test responds with status 422 as expected

Comment: This is why you never do `Model::factory(.....)->toArray()` and manually create an array with desired data... I am 100% sure that if you see the content of `$event`, it has a name and is not empty... Check that. Also, you mostly don't check if you get `422`, you do `$response->assertSessionHasErrors(['name'])`, and you can also assert what field and what error message is returning for that field.

Comment: @matiaslauriti in my model factory I have added `->state(['name' => ''])` and it works as expected. The value of the name field is empty. For your suggestion on on `$response->assertSessionHasErrors(['name'])` for some reason it doesnt work too.

Comment: Can you please share what is the resulting content of `$event` ? There has to be something wrong with `$event` as you said that it is working as expected if you try directly on the URL...

Comment: What response status code do you get? Maybe, just maybe, the empty string is not being treated as null and validation passes. But, by default `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware would be enabled. And I would assume the html form would be posting a null value instead of an empty string. Long shot but worth a check, I think.

Comment: @matiaslauriti question updated

Comment: @user3532758 kindly check the updated question

Comment: postJson is supposed to be used for api/ajax calls, to set proper headers. Your routes ideally would be in api.php route file. Its confusing since the first one is working as you expect. Also, the 302 code means a redirect, no? Are you redirecting after the record is created? For created, its supposed to be 201, at least if the app is api based.

Comment: @OwenKelvin you will have to share your controller as we have no idea what are you doing there.

Comment: @matiaslauriti question updated with controller

Comment: As I previously said, you do not test if it is `422` or `302`, you test if the session has errors  (as I said in my first comment) or you check if it is redirecting where you want, but you mostly never check the status...

Comment: @matiaslauriti oh I didnt realise you already suggested. My bad. I'll be deleting my comment since it's been already said. Owen, 302 is because validation redirects to the previous url with errors. You wont catch 422. Addionally, you can specify a post from url and then check if it's redirected back to that url.

Comment: User still should get `422` as you get an error, it doesn't matter it is validation, it is still an error and the `FormRequest` is redirecting back, so it is strange now to me...

Comment: @matiaslauriti note really, 422 will be registered if its json, otherwise it will be a redirect, error messages bag stored in session. Check here: `convertValidationExceptionToResponse` https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/277c2fbd0cebd2cb194807654d870f4040e288c0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L434

Comment: Yeah, but still, author should check for errors, not http code.